# Find an angle in triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If $\angle ACD = 80^{\circ}$,
$\angle ADC = 70^{\circ}$.
If $AC + CD = AB$
what is $\angle ABC$?

[image]

Comment: What do you have tried?

Comment: There is not sufficient information.  Angle DAC is 30 degrees and angle BDA is 110 degrees but then the best we can say is that angles DAB and DBA add to 70 degrees/

Comment: If you rotate the triangle $ADC$ such that $AC$ land on side $AB$, you can get a new triangle $AEF$, $E$ on side $AB$, then you will find $\Delta AFB$ is identifical to $\Delta ADB$. Then angle $\angle ABD = \angle EBF$ is $\frac{1}{2}\angle AEF = 40^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 2):

Extend $AC$ across $C$ for lenght of $CD$ and you get new point $D'$. Then you find $DCD'$ and $ABD'$ are isosceles and $\angle BDA = \angle D'DA = 110^{\circ}$. So triangles $BDA$ and $D'DA$ are congruent (ssa). Thus $\angle DBA = 40^{\circ}$.